# Sharepoint shows (incomplete) id in "AllItems.aspx"

Tags: sharepoint, office365

In a Sharepoint site:  "https://(company).sharepoint.com/sites/(subject)/Shared%20documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" i see among others the column: "Id". This ID however shows only the numbers f.e. 35.

It does not show the complete number "aadduej-35". The complete number is shown when i open the document properties. There i see "Document-id" with the complete prefix and the id number. How do i arrange that in the .aspx is shown "aadduej-35" instead of "35"

All help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: The Document-id is a column created by yourself? Please share som screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated column and set the formula like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("aadduej-",ID)
```

Or you could format the column with json formatting:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "aadduej-",
      " ",
      "[$ID]"
    ]
  }
}
```